# Bootstrap navbar collapsed alignment

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, less

I have a problem of alignment with my navbar build using Bootstrap3.

This is my navbar when it is not collapsed:

[image]

This is when it is collapsed (viewport under 1000px):

[image]

I want to stack up all the elements, as for example:

- Gassero / -11.8810 (on his right)
- Ordinare
- Paniere
- Conto
- [img] Ciao

This is a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/IKgktG6Ok7) of the code:

This is my nav code:

```
<nav class="userbar" role="navigation">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="img/befair.png" alt="..." class="imglogo">
      </div>

    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navhead">

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="brandname">GASISTAFELICE</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

        <div class="navbar-left">
            <ul ng-controller="gas_controller" class="optionlist nav navbar-nav">
                <li ng-repeat="gasname in gasnames" 
                    ng-class="{ 'active': $index == selectedIndex }"
                    ng-click="itemClicked($index)">    
                    <a href="#/{{peID}}/" ng-click="getID(gasname.id);">
                        {{gasname.name}}
                    </a>
                    <div class="gaslabel">{{gasname.balance}}&#8364;</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="optionlist nav navbar-nav" ng-controller="menu_controller">
              <li markable>
                      <a href="#/{{peID}}/">
                       <i class="fa fa-book"></i>Ordinare
                      </a>
              </li>

             <li markable>
              <a href="#/{{peID}}/paniere">
               <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Paniere
             </a> 
             </li>
              <li markable>
              <a href="#/{{peID}}/conto">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>Conto                       
                </a>
              </li>     
            </ul>

        </div>
     <div class="navbar-right">
         <a class="navpic" href="#/{{peID}}/scheda"><img src="img/user_pic.png" alt="..." class="imgpic"></a>
         <a class="titlenav" href="#/{{peID}}/scheda">Ciao {{name}}</a>
    </div>    

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </nav>
```

And this is my LESS/CSS:

```
.userbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.userbar:before,
.userbar:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.userbar:after {
  clear: both;
}
.userbar:before,
.userbar:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.userbar:after {
  clear: both;
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .userbar {
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
}
.userbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #777777;
}
.userbar .navbar-brand:hover,
.userbar .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #5e5e5e;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.userbar .navbar-text {
  color: #777777;
}
.userbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #777777;
}
.userbar .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.userbar .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.userbar .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.userbar .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.userbar .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #555555;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.userbar .navbar-nav > .disabled > a,
.userbar .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
.userbar .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #cccccc;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.userbar .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #dddddd;
}
.userbar .navbar-toggle:hover,
.userbar .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
.userbar .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
.userbar .navbar-collapse,
.userbar .navbar-form {
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.userbar .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.userbar .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.userbar .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  color: #555555;
}
@media (max-width: 999px) {
  .userbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #777777;
  }
  .userbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .userbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #333333;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .userbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .userbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .userbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #555555;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
  }
  .userbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
  .userbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
  .userbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
    color: #cccccc;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
.userbar .navbar-link {
  color: #777777;
}
.userbar .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #333333;
}
.navhead:before,
.navhead:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.navhead:after {
  clear: both;
}
.navhead:before,
.navhead:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.navhead:after {
  clear: both;
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .navhead {
    float: left;
  }
}
.titlenav {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.titlenav:hover,
.titlenav:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .navbar > .container .titlenav {
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
}
.collapsebar {
  display: none;
  max-height: 340px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.collapsebar.in {
  display: block;
}
.collapsebar:before,
.collapsebar:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.collapsebar:after {
  clear: both;
}
.collapsebar:before,
.collapsebar:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.collapsebar:after {
  clear: both;
}
.collapsebar.in {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .collapsebar {
    width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .collapsebar.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  .collapsebar.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top .collapsebar,
  .navbar-static-top .collapsebar,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .collapsebar {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .navbar-left {
    float: left !important;
  }
  .navbar-right {
    float: right !important;
  }
}

.navbar-left {
  text-align: center;
}

.optionlist {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 7.5px -15px;
  float: left!important;
}
.optionlist:before,
.optionlist:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.optionlist:after {
  clear: both;
}
.optionlist:before,
.optionlist:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.optionlist:after {
  clear: both;
}
.optionlist > li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.optionlist > li > a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.optionlist > li > a:hover,
.optionlist > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.optionlist > li.disabled > a {
  color: #999999;
}
.optionlist > li.disabled > a:hover,
.optionlist > li.disabled > a:focus {
  color: #999999;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.optionlist .open > a,
.optionlist .open > a:hover,
.optionlist .open > a:focus {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border-color: #428bca;
}
.optionlist .nav-divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.optionlist > li > a > img {
  max-width: none;
}
.optionlist > li > a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
@media (max-width: 999px) {
  .optionlist .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .optionlist .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
  .optionlist .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
  }
  .optionlist .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  .optionlist .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .optionlist .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background-image: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .optionlist {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .optionlist > li {
    float: left;
  }
  .optionlist > li > a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .optionlist.navbar-right:last-child {
    margin-right: -15px;
  }
}
.optionlist > li > a {
  padding-bottom: 27px;
}
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}
.navbar-nav {
  margin: 7.5px -15px;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
@media (max-width: 999px) {
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background-image: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    float: left;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
    margin-right: -15px;
  }
}

.nav {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav:before,
.nav:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.nav:after {
  clear: both;
}
.nav:before,
.nav:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.nav:after {
  clear: both;
}
.nav > li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.nav > li > a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.nav > li.disabled > a {
  color: #999999;
}
.nav > li.disabled > a:hover,
.nav > li.disabled > a:focus {
  color: #999999;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.nav .open > a,
.nav .open > a:hover,
.nav .open > a:focus {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border-color: #428bca;
}
.nav .nav-divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
    .nav > li > a > img {
      max-width: none;
}

  .userbar{
    //aggiungere stile navbar
    .navbar; 
    .navbar-default; //taken both from Bootstrap
  }

  .navhead{
    .navbar-header; //taken from Bootstrap
  }

.brandname{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left:5px;
}

  .collapsebar{
        .collapse;
        .navbar-collapse;
  }

.navbar-left{
    text-align:center;
}

.optionlist{
    .nav;
    .navbar-nav;
    float:left!important;
}

.gaslabel{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    color: @gas-color;
}

.navbar-right{
    margin-top:5px;
}
```

Comment: if you could give me just pure css, that would be a lot easier for me to look for your problem. For starters .gaslabel needs to be an anchor or span i'm thinking...

Comment: I have added my (almost) complete CSS, it's really long. Hope it can helps you ;)

Comment: Please provide a working fiddle/bootply of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the nave link into a single ul element then use css for further alignment and finishing.

http://www.bootply.com/tsf41Uxykt#

```
                       <ul class="optionlist nav navbar-nav" ng-controller="menu_controller">
                              <li ng-controller="gas_controller" ng-repeat="gasname in gasnames" ng-class="{ 'active': $index == selectedIndex }" ng-click="itemClicked($index)">    
                                <a href="#/{{peID}}/" ng-click="getID(gasname.id);">
                                  gasname
                                </a>
                                <div class="gaslabel">110100</div>
                              </li>
                              <li markable="">
                                      <a href="#/{{peID}}/">
                                       <i class="fa fa-book"></i>Ordinare
                                      </a>
                              </li>

                             <li markable="">
                              <a href="#/{{peID}}/paniere">
                               <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Paniere
                             </a> 
                             </li>
                              <li markable="">
                              <a href="#/{{peID}}/conto">
                                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>Conto                       
                                </a>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                     <div class="navbar-right">
                                         <a class="navpic" href="#/{{peID}}/scheda"><img src="img/user_pic.png" alt="..." class="imgpic"></a>
                                         <a class="titlenav" href="#/{{peID}}/scheda">Ciao {{name}}</a>
                                    </div> 
                              </li>
                            </ul>
```

Comment: It seems to work but what about the number below gasname? In the collapsed view it's overlapping it.